# Find DIV tags with specific content

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to match the DIV with the checkbox which has the value of `55`. But I get all DIVs including the right one.

How do I make it non-greedy?

```
body.innerHTML.match(/(<div*?)([\s\S]*?)(value="55"?)([\s\S]*?)<\/div>?/)[0]
```

```html
<div class="hidden" data-sort="0"> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="52">one
</div>
<div class="" data-sort="1"> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="53">two
</div>
<div class="" data-sort="2"> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="55">three
</div>
<div class="" data-sort="3"> 
  <input type="checkbox" value="56">four
</div>
```

Comment: Are you limited to just a regex?

Comment: It's in a string and I need it done with regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the data as a string and only have to use plain JS, you can use the following regex:

```
<div\b((?:(?!<\/?div\b)[\s\S])*?value=["']?55\b["']?[\s\S]*?)<\/div>
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/iQ3mI1/4).

```js
var re = /<div\b((?:(?!<\/?div\b)[\s\S])*?value=["']?55\b["']?[\s\S]*?)<\/div>/g; 
var str = '<div class="hidden" data-sort="0"> \n  <input type="checkbox" value="52">one\n</div>\n<div class="" data-sort="1"> \n  <input type="checkbox" value="53">two\n</div>\n<div class="" data-sort="2"> \n  <input type="checkbox" value="55">three\n</div>\n<div class="" data-sort="3"> \n  <input type="checkbox" value="56">four\n</div>';
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    
    document.getElementById("res").value = m[0];
}
```

```html
<input id="res" size="70"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To target the div-element (the DOMNode) you can query it as such:

```
var el = document.querySelector('input[value="55"]').parentNode;
```

If you want to get the complete HTML-code for it, you can then get the outerHTML

```
var html = el.outerHTML; // <div class="" data-sort="2">.....</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not limited to use jQuery, here is a solution,

```js
$('input[value="55"]').parent()
```